# Picture doesnt appear in Overleaf

Tags: image, latex

Does anybody know how to set up commands for displaying pictures in Overleaf?
I was searching everywhere but I found nothing. This is what I'm currently using:

```
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{graphicx}

\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imgname}
  \caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}
\label{fig:}
\FloatBarrier
```

It is displaying a white rectangle with the image name in it:

[image: white rectangle]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using overleaf , then go to the compile button and select Normal instead of fast(draft) from the dropdown menu. The image will appear allright then. Here is a link to the solution : https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Images_not_showing_up

Answer (score 3):

The following minimal example replicates your behaviour:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = .5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that the option `draft` has been passed to [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). It may also be the case that you `\usepackage{graphicx}` *without* the `draft` option, but that you have

```
\documentclass[...,draft,...]{<class>}
```

Identify where you have `draft` passed to the class/package and then remove it.

Comment: I dont have draft in my all project... i dont understand this, i googled everything and nothing work... I have this in my document class -- \documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}

Comment: @Sonya: Something is loading `draft`. Perhaps try adding the `final` option, as in `\usepackage[final]{graphicx}`.

Comment: When using ACL 2019 template to compose a paper, I also met the same issue. Adding `[final]`  solution works as a rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Was figuring this one out for an hour now. I didn't notice there were instructions in the template I was using in Overleaf. It worked when I commented them out.

> If you wish to display your graphics for your own use using
> includegraphic or includegraphics, then comment out the following two
> lines of code. NB: These line *must* be included when submitting to
> BMC. All figure files must be submitted as separate graphics through
> the BMC submission process, not included in the submitted article.

```
%\def\includegraphic{}
%\def\includegraphics{}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial setting you should verify is whether the compiler is in Normal mode rather than Fast (draft) mode. You can find this setting in the drop-down menu under the Recompile button. The Fast (draft) mode is designed to expedite compilation by skipping certain steps, but it may not display included images as a result.

Answer (score -1):

The error lies in not specifying the [final] option in the graphicx package (the [draft] option will give the same error as well). This option does not allow overleaf to load the image properly, to fix the problem you should put the option [final] in the graphicx package, so the line should look like this:

```
\RequirePackage[final]{graphicx}
```

Greetings.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and I found a solution by removing "babel" package.